# Why is a simple MySQL query taking over 5 seconds to execute?

Tags: php, performance, mysqli

**Update 2011/12/12:** Now isolated as FastCGI on my (IIS-based) hosting package. I had them turn it off because a scheduled task kept timing out. I know where I am now. Thanks again, all.

Mark Iliff

---

**Update 2011/12/11:** OK, I have to put my hands up to inadvertent misdirection.

Thanks to your many suggestions I've now identified this as a problem with PHP pages on my hosting package, not specifically MySQL. An empty PHP page still takes 5-6 seconds to load, whereas the same page with an ASP or HTML extension loads too fast to measure. I'm taking this up with my hosting provider.

Sorry for not thinking to check this first and thanks for pitching in: much appreciated.

Mark Iliff

---

I'm relatively new to MySQL/PHP and suspect I'm doing something stupid with the following:

```
        <?
        // Slave page: block/unblock merchant
        $id = $_POST["id"] ;
        $val = $_POST["val"] ;

        if ( isset( $id ) && isset( $val ) ) {
            $conx = mysqli_connect ( "sql05", $dbAc, $dbPwd, "finewine" ) 
                or die ("Conx failed") ;

            // update record
            $sql = "UPDATE wsMerchants SET 
                blockem = ".$val.", updateDT = '".date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" )."' 
                WHERE id = ".$id.";" ;
            $result = mysqli_query( $conx, $sql ) ;

            //tidy
            mysqli_close( $conx ) ;
            };
        ?>

Result of SHOW CREATE:
CREATE TABLE `wsmerchants` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `merchant` text NOT NULL,
 `country` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `blockem` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `benchmark` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `createDT` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updateDT` datetime NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=119 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm calling this from JQuery (using `$.post`). The db table has 29 records and 7 fields.

It works, but incredibly slowly.

With sad old `Access (+ Classic ASP)` queries like this are, for all practical purposes, instantaneous. In MySQL, according to the timer in Firebug, the query takes 5-6 seconds.

I'm running `MySQL 5.0.51a + PHP 5.2.13` in a hosted Windows environment.

I've rootled around other questions in here but they mainly seem to involve complex SQL queries.

Comment: If 5-6 seconds is the time for the ajax call to finish, that includes transfer time, waiting time, and any number of things. How much time does the query alone take?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` for more information about your query.

Comment: Post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE wsMerchants`. Also, how do you measure the speed of the query? Have you tried executing the same query by command line to see if it takes the same amount of time?

Comment: Well I don't know why it's taking so long, but you have some mysql injection issues - maybe you already know that? EX: `$POST['id'] = '1 || 1=1'` to update all rows

Comment: Why do you have `#`s around the date?  You should quote your values, both the date and `$val`.  Also, you shouldn't blindly use `$_POST` in your SQL queries, escape the values first.  As for speed, does the table have an INDEX on the `id` field?

Comment: Mike's question of "Have you tried executing the same query by command line to see if it takes the same amount of time?" would really help you narrow down where the delay is -- whether its AJAX or DB side.  Even running the query through something like phpMySQL and learning the query execution time would be helpful.

Comment: Is the database server on the same box as the web server?  If not, you might have a network configuration issue.  Also, please sanitize your database inputs!

Comment: Thanks to all for responses so far. I'll work through them carefully before rushing into a response (bar a couple of clarifications to follow)

Comment: @Ben it runs off a checkbox in a password-protected area with 3 users. I suspect the injection risk is on the low side ~ yes?

Comment: @Rocket the #s were a typo. The possible values for $_POST are TRUE, FALSE & a positive integer (generated from PHP in the calling page); does my usage amount to "blindly" in this context? Yes, id is indexed

Comment: @Crontab trying to find out whether the db is on the same box; this sounds like a promising angle. "Sanitize"?

Comment: @Mark Iliff  as long as you don't operate your login scripts the same way =) Yes I would say the risk is low. Just keep in mind that everyone on SO including me tends to jump all over possible injection. I have made the habit to always use parameterized queries, I think it's a good one.

Comment: @Mark: About the sanitization angle, see http://bobby-tables.com/ for a good explanation.  Seems the most concise way to explain.

Comment: @Wiseguy OK that was a good lead: "Query took 0.0045 sec".

Comment: @Crontab I'll look at connection issues now

Comment: OK, I've narrowed it down: it's establishing the connection rather than running the query that takes the time. The page takes the same time to load (±) whether or not the query executes.

Comment: @Jason McCreary Is EXPLAIN supposed to work with an UPDATE statement? Dox I've read say it's specific to SELECT

Comment: @Mike Output of SHOW CREATE now added above

Comment: @Mark, you're right. Only `SELECT` is supported. Nonetheless, you could still analyze `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other issues aside, I doubt the bottleneck here is the query.

First, try the query from the MySQL console to ensure your database server is ok.

Then, make a simple test script that only connects to the database and does not perform any queries. Make sure you place something after the connect call so that you can see when it finishes connecting.

That's my guess anyway - is that the bottleneck lies in the database connection.

One more thing, is this an AMP stack (WAMP, XAMPP) in Windows, or are you running PHP through IIS?

Comment: Thanks, @simshaun, and before I'd finished formatting my code! I'll take your advice.

Comment: It's running on my host's server through IIS as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything within that query that would take >5 seconds.  Firebug is probably giving you the time of the total request, not just the query.  That said if the latency is particularly high between the client and application server or the application server and the database then 5 seconds is not unthinkable. I would start by benchmarking the script to figure out exactly what is taking so long.  You can do this by taking timestamps using microtime() throughout the script and then subtracting them to figure out how long each each part of the script is taking.

Comment: Sounds like a slow way to make things faster, but it might come to that! Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This would just be for testing and can be taken out once you'd identified the problem.

Comment: Got it. My (whingey) point was that it sounds like a lot of effort ~ but good to have your idea in case I need to go there

Comment: OK, I buckled down & tried this. Not as hard or time-consuming as it sounded and definitely good advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the conversation in the comments, it seems like your issue is with the network rather than with your code.  My gut tells me it's probably a DNS issue, in which case you may want to look at [this section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dns.html) of the MySQL manual.  Alternatively, try using an IP address rather than `"sql05"` in your connection string, see if that speeds things up.

Comment: Thanks. As now noted above, it's a problem with hosting PHP in general *blush*